# Need help running Ubuntu Minimal with e17

Tags: ubuntu-minimal, enlightenment

Recently I have decided to opt for an optimized system for myself. I chose Ubuntu Mini 12.04 Precise Pangolin.

The installation is not an issue, and I can boot into the basic command prompt and login with ease. The first thing I did was

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After this, I am not sure what to do:

- Is there anything I need to install before getting and installing e17?
- How do I get and install e17, and then make it boot into desktop automatically when I turn on the machine?
- I'd prefer the commands, as I am new to Ubuntu and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess it would be best to tell you go read some documentation first...

Anyway. To update the system `apt-get update` is not enough. This just gets you a list of updated packages... Use the following to update:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get clean
```

the `apt-get clean` will remove the downloaded packages from the disk cache, so it's optional.

After that use the following to install e17 and set it as default desktop environment:

```
sudo apt-get install e17
sudo update-alternatives --set x-window-manager /usr/bin/enlightenment_start
```

I hope that gets you started...

But seriously read the docs...

Comment: There are no docs, but thanks for the suggestion. Some learn best by having someone show them how to do something.

Comment: Alright, so after I input all of those codes, I restart, only to boot to a black screen.

Comment: I googled "the docs" and there were too many options to narrow down which one I needed.

Comment: When you say "black screen", can you switch to a text-console using "Ctrl+Alt+F1"? If so, maybe you're missing a display manager or there is a problem with your x-server...

Checkout http://www.bodhilinux.com/, as this is a ubuntu based distribution using elightenment as desktop env.